# How to make a batch file that works in the current folder and delete specific files?

Tags: list, file, batch-file, cmd, directory

I've been searching around how to make a batch file that works in it's current folder that it was executed. Then uses a filelist.txt along with the batch in that same folder to delete the files listed in that filelist.txt

It boils down like this
I run the batch file -> Batch file uses current folder it is in -> Uses filelist.txt the batch file is with -> batch file deletes the files listed in the filelist.txt

Help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the batch file will run in its current directory.

What you are asking can be accomplished with one line.

```
for /f %%i in (filelist.txt) do if exist %%i del %%i
```

If the files are in different folders you will need to specify the full path for each file in filelist.txt

ex.

C:\users\Johndoe\desktop\picture1.jpg

C:\users\Johndoe\documents\picture2.jpg